# Get current id in GridView and insert it as id in another table on button click

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview, sqlcommand

I have a table called Documents and a GridView where I display some of its info. Inside an ItemTemplate I have put buttons as a rating system. What I want to do is to get the DocumentID from the Documents table and use it as ID in a table called RatingTable with DocumentID as primary and foreign key, and rating as a tinyint.

Here is the code for the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="SearchView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SearchView_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="Ingen oppføringer">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="Filnavn" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ReportCount" HeaderText="Antall rapporteringer" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Tags" HeaderText="Tags" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseCode" HeaderText="Fagkode" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton class="myButtonLink" ImageUrl="~/Images/empty_star.png" ID="rate1" runat="server" OnClick="rate1_Click"/>
                    <asp:ImageButton class="myButtonLink" ImageUrl="~/Images/empty_star.png" ID="rate2" runat="server" OnClick="rate2_Click"/>
                    <asp:ImageButton class="myButtonLink" ImageUrl="~/Images/empty_star.png" ID="rate3" runat="server" OnClick="rate3_Click"/>
                    <asp:ImageButton class="myButtonLink" ImageUrl="~/Images/empty_star.png" ID="rate4" runat="server" OnClick="rate4_Click"/>
                    <asp:ImageButton class="myButtonLink" ImageUrl="~/Images/empty_star.png" ID="rate5" runat="server" OnClick="rate5_Click"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Nedlastingslink">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="downloadbutton" runat="server" Text="Last ned" OnClick="Download_Click"
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Rapporter" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Small">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="reportbutton" runat="server" Text="Rapporter dokument" OnClick="Report_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code behind where I try to insert the value of the rating into the RatingTable:

```
protected void updaterating(int rating)
    {
        //string value = SearchView.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO RatingTable (DocumentID, Rating) VALUES(@DocumentID, @Rating)"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentID", value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", rating);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }

    protected void rate1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        updaterating(1);
    }

    protected void rate2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        updaterating(2);
    }

    protected void rate3_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        updaterating(3);
    }

    protected void rate4_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        updaterating(4);
    }

    protected void rate5_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        updaterating(5);
    }
```

Here is what the RatingTable tools like:

```
[RatingTable] (
[DocumentID] INT     NOT NULL,
[Rating]     TINYINT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DocumentID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_RatingTable_Documents] FOREIGN KEY ([DocumentID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Documents] ([DocumentId])
```

);

What I'm trying to do is when I press one of the ImageButtons in the TemplateField "Rating", I want it to get the current DocumentID for the row I'm in, and use this to insert it into the RatingTable as a primary key with the value of the star clicked. In the updaterating function in the code behind, I have commented out some lines where I tried to use DataKeyNames in the GridView to get the ID, but that gives an empty GridView.

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SearchView.DataKeyNames = new string[]{"DocumentID"};
            BindGrid();
        }
```

I added this to try to fetch the DataKeyNames right before I bind the grid, but the GridView is still empty.

I also changed the string value because I was using the wrong attribute:

```
protected void updaterating(int rating)
    {
        string value = SearchView.DataKeyNames.ToString();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO RatingTable (DocumentID, Rating) VALUES(@DocumentID, @Rating)"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentID", value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", rating);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're not really telling us which part of your code is not working as expected and what exactly your problem is.

Comment: The string value in the code behind and the AddWithValue for the DocumentID was something I tried by using DataKeyNames as DocumentID in the GridView, but then the GridView wouldn't show anything.

Comment: I'm sorry. When I click one of the buttons, I get an SQLException because @DocumentID is not declared. But I am not sure how to get the DocumentID and insert it.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add these details as well as the exact exception you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `DataKeyName` to your GridView. If I understand the question correctly, that would be `DocumentID`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="SearchView" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="SearchView_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
    EmptyDataText="Ingen oppføringer"
    DataKeyNames="DocumentID">
```

Then when you run this line:

```
string value = SearchView.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();
```

The GridView actually knows what the `DataKey` is. Since you are using `SelectedDataKey`, there also must be a selected row for this property to have a value.

To find the index of the row when it is not selected, you need to find the row that the button that was clicked is contained within.

```cs
protected void rate1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton rate1 = (ImageButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)rate1.NamingContainer;
    DataKey key = SearchView.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex];

    // Now you have your key, use it how you'd like.
    // This may mean passing it as another variable
    // to your updaterating method.

    updaterating(1);
}
```

Comment: When I had the DataKeyNames in the GridView, the GridView is empty. I also changed the SelectedDataKey to SearchView.DataKeyNames.ToString();

Comment: Using `SearchView.DataKeyNames.ToString();` won't work either because `DataKeyNames` is a string array. You need to find the index of your row within the DataKeyNames array to get its value.

Comment: Adding a `DataKeyName` wouldn't cause no data to be bound to the GridView. If the `DataKeyName` does not exist in the data source, you would get an error.

Comment: I see. Any suggestions to how to find the index? I am not very experienced with using ASP.Net.

Comment: I added a string argument to the updaterating function. But the line DataKey key = SearchView.DataKeyNames[row.DataItemIndex]; gives an error: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataKey'

Comment: Sorry, meant to use `DataKeys`, not `DataKeyNames`. See my edit.

Comment: This worked by using the key.Value and casting it to int, because the DocumentID is of type int. Thank you very much! By the way, I discovered the error of why my GridView was empty when using DataKeyNames; I had forgot to select the DocumentID...

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you were able to get it working.